# Warning: Attribute Unavailable: Content Edge Inset in iPhone SDK for iOS versions prior to 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

I took over a project from someone, and I am getting a LOT of these warning when I build:

.../SelectCharacterMenu.xib: warning: Attribute Unavailable: Content Edge Inset in iPhone SDK for iOS versions prior to 3.0

.../GameTypeSelectionMenu.xib: Content Edge Inset in iPhone SDK for iOS versions prior to 3.0

This one has me stumped. I am using the latest version of XCode, the SDK is iOS 8.1, and our deployment target is set for 5.1 and later (not my choice!) So why would I get warnings for 3.0 or prior? What simple thing am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the XIB files set up using a format for iOS < 3.0? There are lots of different options for the format for XIBs, and you get warnings if your interfaces use features that aren't supported by the version of a file. That's my guess.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I will check that out and report back. Never thought of that. Stand by

Comment: Worked. They were left unset completely. Once I set their value, the warnings went away. Thank you.